# Delete certain and previous line from textfile using batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I was hoping someone would be able to offer me assistance with the following issue please? I have a text file which has some lines of data, what I'm trying to do is run a script which will delete all lines that contain  " Deactivate:              yes".  This i have working so far, however I wish to also delete the line above this line?
Hopefully that makes sense.  So far to remove the line I have the following:-

```
for %%t in (E:\test\test.txt) do (
    ren "%%~ft" "%%~nxt.txt"
    findstr /v /r /c:"^[  Deactivate:              yes]*$" "%%~ft.txt" > "%%~ft"
)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (test.txt) do (
    set "_line=%%A"
    rem *** Test if current line contains "Deactivate:" substring
    if "!_line!"=="!_line:Deactivate:=!" (
        rem *** if does not contain, output previous line, and save current line
        if defined _prev echo !_prev!
        set "_prev=!_line!"
    ) else (
        rem *** if contain, skip previous and current lines
        set "_prev="
    )
)
if defined _prev echo %_prev%
endlocal
```